# как реализовать консоль в c#

Tags: c#

Захотелось сделать что-то типо консоли CMD, вообщем консольку с командами простую.
(Вводишь например time - выдает время.)
Пробовал через case - закрывается сразу.
Вообщем просто хочу узнать что юзать для создания такого.

И ещё одну маленькую вещь - вот ввёл команду - получил результат, и как вернуться обратно к вводу команд?

```
Console.Title = "Console";
Console.WriteLine("  ");
Console.Write(" User> ");
```

Comment: используйте цикл

Comment: А если не сложно - можно пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с простым циклом

```
var exit = false;
while(!exit)
{
    switch(Console.ReadLine())
    {
        case "exit":
            exit = true;
            break;
        case "time":
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Неизвестная команда!");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку CS0234
Тип или имя пространства имен "WriteLine" не существует в пространстве имен "Console" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку).

Comment: @Zekoy видимо вы неправильно скопировали мой код. Попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: Я всё скопировал полностью и вставил после static void Main(string[] args)
        но всё равно три эти ошибки(

Comment: @Zekoy вот [так](https://i.imgur.com/0bAMosh.png) выглядит программа, вот [так](https://i.imgur.com/H0TBWJJ.png) выглядит тип проекта и версия фреймворка, сверяйте с тем, что делаете вы.

Comment: Простите, это была моя ошибка, я назвал программу "Console", извините.